# How to display a set of images in GridView, with their normal size

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

If I have set of images with the same size 211px x 165px , how display them with a grid view with maintaining the original ratio between the height and the width.  where it is required to display two items in each row. I have already could to do that but the images appear stretched vertically. 
here is a screenshot of what I get. Notice that the `gridview` cell is larger than the image
[image]

**`gridview` layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/header" />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvCategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

gridview cell layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/include21nh"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/include21"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCategoryImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/img1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCategoryName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_fading"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Crispy Chicken and Sandwich"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` attribute inside an `ImageView` that represents an item in your `GridView`. As the documentation says:

> CENTER_INSIDE -   Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).

You can find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). Hope this helps.